# WkHTMLtoPDF not loading controller directives of Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, wkhtmltopdf

I am working on Angular 1.5.8 and WkHTMLtoPDF 0.13.0 alfa.
I am running WkHTMLtoPDF from cmd in Windows with the following params:

```
wkhtmltopdf --user-style-sheet 
file:///C:\Users\joha\MyProject\public\css\print.css --enable-local-file-
access   --javascript-delay 8000
"http://localhost:9000/print="X"&code="code"&token="XXX"&user=user1"  
C:\tmp\testPrint.pdf
```

This url calls an Scala Service, who returns:
Ok(views.html.myView(javascripts, request.getQueryString("code").getOrElse("No error retrived"), token, objectType)).withSession("user" -> Json.toJson(tL).toString())

In myView.html I use my own Angular directive called print-canvas which has its owns controller

```
@(javascripts: Seq[String], code:String, token:String, objectType:String)
<html ng-app="visioanris_ui">
    <head>
        @includes()
    </head>

    <body>
        <script src='/angular/lib/jquery/jquery.min.js'></script>
        <print-canvas code="@code" token="@token" object-type="@objectType">
        </print-canvas>

        <h2>CODE: @code</h2>
        <h2>TOKEN: @token</h2>
        <h2>OBJECT TYPE: @objectType</h2>

    </body>
    @for(script <- javascripts) {
    <script src='@routes.Assets.versioned(script)' type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    }
</html>
```

My problem is print-canvas directive controller does not work.
Somebody knows why WkHTMLtoPDF is not seeing print-canvas controller?
I say WkHTMLtoPDF is not seeing my controller because I am calling a service within constructor printCanvasController and this service never was called, but if I run my service inside chrome, printCanvasController Constructor is called

My print-canvas directive is:

```
directivesModule.directive('printCanvas', ['$compile',
(@$compile) ->
    restrict: 'AE'
    transclude:true
    scope:{
        code:"=code"
        token:"=token"
        objectType:"=objectType"
    } 
    controllerAs: 'me'
    controller: 'printCanvasController'
   templateUrl: 
   '/assets/partial/directives/printDirective/analysisPrintView.html'
   ])
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Never used it personally, but try to use --debug-javascript and see what happens. Also add like `console.log("I am a logging statement, look at me!");console.error("I am an ERROR, look at me!");` to see that it actually works. Might have to run it in console, not sure where it outputs but I'm guessing stderr

Comment: Thanks four yor answer! Seems wkhtml does not like angularJs. I testedsome angularJs applications and many of them does not work. So I decided to use google chrome headless and it works! Regards,

Comment: Great! If you can, add an answer to your own question what your solution looks like it so that people can find it and get help - I'm curious to see how you managed to solve the situation as well :)

Comment: having a similar problem, i see that is is working with angularjs 1.2 but not with 1.5 any thoughts?